# Store Credit Card information in Account Object in Salesforce

Tags: account, encryption, platform-encryption

I wanted to check if we can store CredtiCard information (Using Encrypted Field) on Account Object in Salesforce and would it still be PCI Compliant?

Thanks
Ritu

Comment: This would increase your PCI scope. SF is PCI compliant BUT since you are storing them there is more burden on you for OCI compliance. The least risk is to store tokens and not full PAN information. Encrypted or not

Comment: Salesforce PCI Attestation of Compliance link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175615&type=1